# How do I get the URI of a music from the MediaStore?

Tags: android, media, android-contentprovider

I can get the artist, title and track information from the MediaStore, but how do I get the path or uri of the media file I'm trying to play?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you query the `MediaStore` content provider, the column you want is:

```
MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
```

If the media is on the SD card (or internal storage), that will be the path to the file.

Comment: that's a nice answer. Works really fine. Thanks.